# div not displaying results

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a rock, paper, scissors game.

I get an error in chrome console saying `'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')'` without even clicking on anything. And my `div` DOM content isn't loaded. Here is it in codepen, however the 1st problem isn't showing here: https://codepen.io/mofodreamer/pen/WNmvaGN

```
document.getElementById("rock").addEventListener("click", () => game("rock"));
document.getElementById("paper").addEventListener("click", () => game("paper"));
document.getElementById("scissors").addEventListener("click", () => game("scissors"));
```

```
function updateResult(result) {
    const resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
    resultDiv.textContent = result;
    resultDiv.textContent = (`Your choice: ${userChoice}, the computer's: ${computerChoice}. ${result} Your score is ${userScore}, computer's score is ${computerScore}`);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) - The JavaScript is running before the HTML is there

Comment: Of course, the question would be helped if you included the HTML on which the JavaScript was running...

Comment: evolutionxbox's suggested duplicate seems very plausible.  I myself have encountered the problem that arises when the `<script>` element appears before the DOM element you are trying to get by id.  But even more helpful than providing a "problem isn't showing here" example would be a "problem **is** showing here" example.

Comment: you are missing the `defer` attribute in `<script src="scripts.js" defer></script>`